# Printing the return value

Tags: ruby, return-value

I copied and ran the following code taken from the book *Programming in Ruby: the Pragmatic Programmer's Guide*:

```
a = [ 1, 'cat', 3.14 ]
a[0]
```

The book says the program is supposed to give `1`, but it doesn't, it gives nothing. Then, I tried the next exercise:

```
a = [ 'ant', 'bee', 'cat', 'dog', 'elk' ]
a[0]
a[3]
```

which is supposed to return `"ant"` and `"dog"`, but still, it does nothing. Can anyone tell me where I am screwing up?

Answer (score 3):

Try entering these lines into an IRB session instead. You'll see promised results. If you want to run it from a file, then you have to do something different.

```
a[0]
```

This will *evaluate* the expression. IRB will show you its value, but running it from a file does nothing. You must explicitly *print* it to the standard output. Something like this:

```
puts a[0]
```

### Update

Here's an example IRB session

```
% irb
1.9.3p125 :001 > a = [ 'ant', 'bee', 'cat', 'dog', 'elk' ]
 => ["ant", "bee", "cat", "dog", "elk"]
1.9.3p125 :002 > a[0]
 => "ant"
1.9.3p125 :003 > a[3]
 => "dog"
```

I suggest that you stick to IRB. It is much better for learning because of its interactivity.

Answer (score 1):

you should use `p` or `print` or `puts` statement to see the output,when you will be running `arraytest.rb` from the command prompt. Do change as below and run your code.

```
a = [ 'ant', 'bee', 'cat', 'dog', 'elk' ]
p a[0]
p a[3]
```

Comment: Ok, thanks! That did work! I knew I was missing something fundamental. But how is the reader supposed to guess that, since the book doesn't say anything about adding the p statement to it? It hasn't even covered p statements yet.

Comment: The author probably doesn't mention an editor either.  But any Ruby book will likely talk about IRB.  Do these things in IRB while going through immediate examples like this, you will enjoy getting instant feedback.